# Bind keyboard keys to midi controller keys

Tags: keyboard, midi, midi-controller-keyboard

Is there any program I can use to map keyboard keys to midi controller keys so that I can use my midi controller piano for typing ?

---

The reason I want this is because I am willing to create a virtual piano program, but it will be really hard (not that I even know how to) to also imply some sound library or hardware programming so I am trying to find a program that does the midi mapping and allows me to use my midi controller anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is, e.g., [Bome MIDI Translator](http://www.bome.com/products/miditranslator/overview/classic).

However, for controlling a virtual piano with a 'real' MIDI keyboard, it would be a much better idea to read events directly from the MIDI port.

Comment: Thank you. It took me a little time until I find out how to do that. Then it took time again to bind all the keys I want. But it worked perfectly after all.